# how can I get a child from its own child value in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: here my firebase Realtime database]

1. I have database child called "**boardValues**"
2. **boardValues** have nested child data like **p01, p02, p03**....**and so on, it contains Integer value like **1, 2, 3,**....
3. inShort, path is **firebase/Game/boardValues/p01**

Aim:

1. when user enter **1**, its have to show (**"YOU ENTERED 1, AND THIS IS CHILD OF firebase/Game/boardValues/p01"**)
2. so basically, If a have a **child value** then for the help of that child value, I need show that **child value(Key)**
3. For example I have value **3**, then screen have to show a **("p03")** as a output

Answer (score 0):

If you know the path `Game/EFYKUY/boardValues` and the value `3` for a key under that, you can find that key with:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Game/EFYKUY/boardValues");
Query query = ref.orderByValue().equalTo(3);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvents(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("DB", snapshot.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

The `for` loop is needed as there might be multiple child keys with the same value.